# Sum the values of a column based on the timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
           timestamp    side    price   amount  fee
0   2018-12-14 13:00:00 buy  0.00338508 5   0.005
1   2018-12-14 13:00:00 buy  0.00337829 5   0.005
2   2018-12-14 14:00:00 buy  0.00338089 5   0.005
3   2018-12-14 14:00:00 buy  0.00338079 1   0.001
4   2018-12-14 15:00:00 sell 0.00338838 8   0.00002711
5   2018-12-14 15:00:00 sell 0.00339132 8   0.00002713
6   2018-12-14 15:00:00 buy  0.00337999 5   0.005
7   2018-12-14 16:00:00 sell 0.00339373 5   0.00001697
```

What I need to do is to create a column which would sum the values of the column 'amount' which have the same timestamp. So for the timestamp `2018-12-14 13:00:00` the new column would look like this:

```
          timestamp    side    price   amount  fee sum
0   2018-12-14 13:00:00 buy  0.00338508 5   0.005 10
1   2018-12-14 13:00:00 buy  0.00337829 5   0.005 10
```

I tried with the following code: `df_statistics_hour['traded_volume'] = float(df_statistics_hour['amount'].sum())` but of course there is the same value in each cell of the new column, any idea on how to proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Use `df_statistics_hour['traded_volume'] = df_statistics_hour.groupby('timestamp')['amount'].transform('sum')`

Comment: Yup indeed, thanks!